# Invalid after rescue exception in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a text form to get URL from users.

Controller:

```
def create
  link = Link.new(set_url_params)
  if link.save
     redirect...
  else
     flash[:notice] = "error"
  end
end
```

In my model I have a method to add http if a given link does not have it:

```
  before_validation :clean_link

  def clean_link
    self.url = "http://#{url}" unless self.url =~ /^https?:\/\//
  end
```

Now I'd like to valid the url responds (+ get the final link after redirections) and save it or show an error message:

```
validate :response?

      def response?
        begin
          self.url = HTTParty.head(self.url).request.last_uri.to_s
        rescue SocketError
          false
        end
      end



Example with valid URL:  
  input: cvcka.cz 
  clean_link: http://cvcka.cz
  respond? https://cvcka.cz

  link.valid? True

Invalid URL: 
  input: dada
  clean_link: http://dada 
  respond?: rescue exception and return false

link.valid? - it returns true instead of false.
```

Why link.valid? with a string "dada" is true instead of false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an entry to the model's errors so that the model's `valid?` state will be false.

```
  def response?
    begin
      self.url = HTTParty.head(self.url).request.last_uri.to_s
    rescue SocketError
      errors.add(:url, "Not a responsive URL")
      return false
    end
  end
```